# How to find which Node.js file is running now

Tags: node.js

I forgot what node.js file now running on port 3000. How can I know it?
I executed the command

```
lsof -c node
```

but it did not help me find out the name of the file.
(Linux OS)

Answer (score 0):

`ps auxww | grep node` should do the trick.

Comment: This command shows what the argument was passed to the command "node". It does not show the full path to the running file

Comment: if you have a running file, that should be one of the arguments passed to node.